# Hard/extreme penalties

Tags: vocabulary

Should I use the adjectives ***(sharp, hard or extreme)*** with 'penalty' ? According to Longman dictionary, we use (severe / stiff / heavy / tough/ harsh) with it.
Can I say you will face extreme / sharp penalties if you don't observe the law.
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/penalty

Comment: [sharp and hard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sharp+penalty%2C+hard+penalty%2C+extreme+penalty%2C+severe+penalty&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) are not really used to describe a penalty. Not that they're wrong, just rarely used in that way.

Comment: What's sharp supposed to mean here? It can mean prompt, brisk, piercing, stylish, as well as harsh. Sharp punishment might be one that happens immediately or soon.

Answer (score -1):

Any of the adjectives "*sharp*", "*hard*" or "*extreme*" can modify "penalty" in such a context, and the usage would be natural. The same is true of "*severe*",  "*stiff*", "*heavy*", or "*harsh*". An adjective used almost exclusively in this conte3xt is "*draconian*" referring to a very excessive punishment or penalty.